# Rails 4.1 enum values not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

This is the model which has the enum:

```
class Admin::Dispatcher < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum any_or_all: [:any_condition,:all_condition]
    belongs_to :vendor_service,class_name: "VendorService"
    belongs_to :admin_filter_group,class_name: "Admin::FilterGroup"
    belongs_to :admin_filter_values,class_name: "Admin::FilterValues"
    has_many :dispatcher_conditions,class_name: "Admin::DispatcherCondition",foreign_key: "admin_dispatcher_id"
    has_many :dispatcher_actions,class_name: "Admin::DispatcherAction",foreign_key: "admin_dispatcher_id"
    has_many :dispatcher_emails,class_name: "Admin::DispatcherEmail",foreign_key: "admin_dispatcher_id"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dispatcher_conditions, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :dispatcher_actions, allow_destroy: true
    attr_accessor :service,:vendor,:on,:condition_type,:condition,:filter,:filter_value,:any_or_all
end
```

Please refer the screen shot below where you can see that I have tried updating the model but it is not getting updated:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enum works, but the `any_or_all` is not saved, since it's a property on the `Admin::Dispatcher` class that conflicts with the `attr_accessor`.

You can remove the `any_or_all` from the `attr_accessor` list and it will work.

It seems that this happens because the `enum` method [defines a `#{name}=` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/368cca51d25fa15c0ddc8743b5904c4d5ce93e74/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L96) on the object, which is overriden by the `attr_accessor`.

Comment: oh! I need that attr_accessor as well!!! I think I can change that in the form that I am using. Thanks.. great catch. I will check and get back!